# How to Remember Pass Values Without Exposing To HTML? (NodeJS/ejs)

Tags: node.js

I tried to Google search but I did not even know what to search for!

My current problem is: say I have a customer order an item, it will show in his list of orders and he can then edit the order in the future by clicking a button next to the order.

Currently the button submits a hidden form which contains all information needed to identify a particular order and this form is passed into the edit order page through a post request. Although the form is hidden, when page source is viewed the information will still be accessible by the user.

How do I avoid exposing the information to the user? I.e do everything in the backend.

```
<form method="POST" action="/edit_order">
    <input type="hidden" name="owner_email" value=<%=all.owner_email %>>
    <input type="hidden" name="owner_email" value=<%=all.transactionId %>>
    <input type="hidden" name="start_date" value=<%=moment(all.start_date).format() %>>
    <input type="hidden" name="end_date" value=<%=moment(all.end_date).format() %>>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Change this order</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe use AJAX-request?

Comment: @Anatoly hmm, I'll look into passing objects to and from front end using Ajax thanks!